# toggling from profile image to underlying video

Tags: jquery, client-side-scripting

I am making a profile page where when the profile picture is clicked, the image hides and and underlying short clip becomes visible and plays. Then when the video is clicked, the video will hide and the image will show again. Here is the code that I have to execute the first part but it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#avatar {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}

.picture {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}

#playbutton {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position:absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
}


.video
{
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
visibility: hidden;

}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<section class=pictureandvideo>
    <a id=togglepicture href="#">
    <div class=picture>
        <img id=avatar src="avatar.jpg"></img>
        <img id=playbutton src="opagueplayicon.png"></img>



//  The playbutton icon hovers over the avatar. Both make up the collective image.

    </div>



    <div class=video>

         // Video underlying the image

        <video  id=video1 width="200" height="200">
        <source src="Produce_0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="Produce_0.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
    </div>
    </a>

</section>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'/>
<script>
$('#togglepicture').click(function({$(this).children('.picture').toggle('fast').find('.video').css('visibility','visible').get(0).play()});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can achieve it like this, but you have to remove the anchor and the event to the anchor with id `#togglepicture`

```
$(".picture").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
$(".video").show();
});

$(".video").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
$(".picture").show();
});
```